# R Tidy solution to select from group_by output based on a column's data availability

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have following R dplyr dataframe in df_pub (Science/Nature Publication Data)

[image]

Please note that there are same PMID (or paper) with contributing authors in each row (Authors info is not shown here).

I need to select and store publications (PMID) which has no email attached to it and store the last observation of it in data-frame.

Actually I want to remove all PMIDs having any email in any observation. I need to collect the Publications (PMIDs) which does not have an attached email, and then find the last author or last observation (usually she/he/xe are the group leader or PI, we'll contact them manually and request them to update their email).

So for the example above, the expected output will not contain PMID 22522932 because it has an email attached. For other PMIDs only the last row of each such PMID will be stored.

I started with this but then lost

```
df_pub %>%
  group_by(pmid) %>%
  filter(is.na(email)) # This does not do the expected
```

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I don't know why that code wouldn't have worked

Comment: This might help: https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/basic-r-rows-that-contain-the-maximum-value-of-a-variable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this will do what you want:

```
df_pub %>% 
  group_by(pmid) %>% 
  filter(!any(!is.na(email)),
         row_number() == n())
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how you have figured out the problem from my very lousy description. Cakes and cookies.

Comment: Do you want to keep the last observation in group _and then_ remove PMIDs with emails? So if the last observation in group (PMID) has an email, that PMID will not be included in the final dataset. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Actually I want to remove all PMIDs having any email in any observation. I need to collect the Publications (PMIDs) which does not have an attached email, and then find the last author or last observation (usually she/he/xe are the group leader or PI, we'll contact them manually and request them to update their email).

Comment: @jorge-mendes provided the correct solution, I think. So, I am marking their answer as correct.

Comment: I updated the answer again. Let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, both your and Jorge Mendes' solution work and yield same output. I am not an expert who can tell which solution is more Tidy-er than other.

Comment: Definitely mine.

Comment: Yes. It's yours. Because it is done in a single filter query.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted. It checks which pmids have no email attached and then shows only the last row.

```
df_pub %>% 
    group_by(pmid) %>% 
    filter(sum(is.na(email)) == n()) %>% #chooses pmids that number of NAs equals number os rows
    filter(row_number() == n()) #chooses the last row for each pmid
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Bravo. I am still puzzled that how you three figured out what  I was asking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Might not be the most concise code, but I think it solves your question.

```r
# Sample dataframe
  pmid   email No
1    1    <NA>  1
2    1    <NA>  2
3    1    <NA>  3
4    2 a@b.com  4
5    2    <NA>  5

# Logic
val <- df$pmid[!is.na(df$email)] %>% unique()
df[!df$pmid %in% val, ] %>% 
  group_by(pmid) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Result
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   pmid email      No
  <dbl> <fct>   <int>
1     1 NA          3
```

Comment: Thanks. Jorge Mendes has provided the elegant tidy code.